# cx_freeze - executable still looking in local directories

Tags: python, numpy, cx-freeze

I started Python last week in order to make my life easier at work.
In order to make my work profitable to others at the office, I decided to create an executable using cx_freeze.

After troubleshooting a lot of small dependencies issues and so on, I finally got to the point where my .exe file worked properly **on my computer**.
Unfortunately, when trying to launch the .exe file on someone else's computer (I am the only one using python, which is the reason why I build the .exe file) the following error appeared : 
[error message - missing dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEE8z.png)

I have been looking all over the internet to find an answer to my question, but I could not find anyone with the same problem as mine.

**Technical information :**
I use Win10, python3.6 and cx_freeze 5.0.1 !

My code is quite basic and only plots datas then outputs png files. Here below my setup :

```
import sys
import os
import matplotlib
import scipy
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from multiprocessing.context import Process

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\gmignot\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\gmignot\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

includefiles = ['ColoredMapInput.csv',r"C:\Users\gmignot\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",r"C:\Users\gmignot\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\DLLs\tk86t.dll", os.path.dirname(scipy.__file__)]

setup(
    name = Test1",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "First attempt to python",
    options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles,"packages": ['numpy','pandas','numpy.lib.format'],'include_msvcr': True,"includes":['matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg','tkinter','multiprocessing']}}, 
    executables = [Executable("first_attempt.py",base = "Win32GUI")])
```

It looks like the .exe file keeps looking for numpy in a local directory (when required by Pandas). But I have the numpy folder in my build folder...

Do you have any idea where this issue could come from ? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Thanks a lot and regards,

gmignot

Comment: Hi guys ! 

I have been looking for a solution for a few weeks now and I have not been able to find anyone with the same problem.
It looks like it comes from Pandas call to numpy. But I have no idea how to tell it to look in the build folder rather than in my local libs. 

Thanks a lot for your time.

Regards,

gmignot

Comment: I know this is an old question and that this does not really provide an answer to it, but here goes : On the "it looks like the .exe file keeps looking in a local directory", I think, based on this discussion https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/214, that it only **looks** like cx_freeze is looking there. Meaning it actually is looking for numpy in its local build but it **shows** the directory where numpy was when the program was freezed.

Answer (score 0):

I use linux but i'm sure that you must substitute 'gmignot' user with an enviroment variable that contains your user name. In linux is HOME, i don't know on Windows. To use enviroment variable on python type `os.environ['variable_name']`

Comment: Hi ! 
Thanks a lot for your quick answer.

I used environment variables in order to access the proper TCL and TK libraries.
Correct me if I'm wrong : using my username enables to access the libraries I want to include in my .exe. Once the build is complete, the exe file and libraries should only reference other libs contained in the "build" folder.
So what is the point of using environment variables ? 
Sorry for the lack of knowledge ... 

Regards,